# M-x replace-regexp uppercases words in replacement text based on the first letter present in the line

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

So, I have the following buffer:

```
1234
Red
blue
green
yellow

# colors

orange
```

Now, if I run `M-x replace-regexp` I get odd results. If I have the search string: `^\(.+\)$` and the replacement string: `example string:\1` I get the following output:

```
example string:1234
Example String:Red  
example string:blue
example string:green
example string:yellow

example string:# colors

example string:orange
```

As can be seen, I get `Example String:Red` instead of the expected `example string:Red`. What's the deal with this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f replace-regexp` says:

> Preserve case in each match if `case-replace` and `case-fold-search`
>   are non-nil and `REGEXP` has no uppercase letters.

Either set `replace-case` to `nil` before you run the replacement command or write a new command that binds `case-replace` to `nil` and then calls `replace-regexp`.  Something like this:

```el
(defun my-replace ()
 "..."
 (interactive)
 (let ((case-replace  nil))
   (replace-regexp "^\\(.+\\)$" "example string:\\1")))
```

See node [Regexp Replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) of the Emacs manual.

Comment: How do you pass an argument in the way you're describing to a command?

Comment: I accepted this answer, but that doesn't really solve the problem for the general case though.

Comment: What's the general case? You can use arbitrary Lisp code in the replacement string. With that, you can use function `downcase`. The possibilities, just like the number of "general cases", are endless.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to create  a version of the replace `M-x replace-regexp` command where `case-replace` is bound to `nil` without having to re-implement the whole thing?

Comment: You're not reimplementing "the whole thing". You're just **binding a variable** around "the whole thing". Alternatively, just **set the variable** before calling the command; then set it back again, if you want. A global variable controls this behavior - for your convenience. You can **customize** the variable, to get your preferred behavior by default in every Emacs session. Or you can **set** the variable temporarily. Or you can **bind** it in a particular command (use case). It all depends on just what you need/want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `case-replace` option.  If you disable that option, the replacement case will be as you entered it for all instances.

The *purpose* of the option is more to maintain the original case for replacements like `red -> green` in which case:

```
red
Red
RED
```

would become

```
green
Green
GREEN
```

If you disable that option, the replacements would be:

```
green
green
green
```